# "Tag Part in (...) is Protected"

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am currently writing a module that's supposed to take some data points of 2-dimensional function (a 3 x N matrix) and draw contour plot of approximation based on those points (functions and variables for fitting are provided by user).
The "header" looks like this:

```
project4[dataPoints_, functionList_, fittingVarsList_, plotArgs___] := 
 Module[{fitFunc, functionContourPlot, dataPointsXY, pointsPlot, 
   xList, yList},
```

Example of usage:

```
project4[data, {1, x, y, x y, x^2, y^2}, {x, y}]
```

(where data = {{x1,y1,f1}...})

After checking if the arguments are valid I do:

```
fitFunc = Fit[dataPoints, functionList, fittingVarsList];
```

To obtain the approximation. 
Then I want to obtain plot of it by doing:

```
functionContourPlot = ContourPlot[fitFunc, {fittingVarsList[[1]], xMin, xMax},{fittingVarsList[[2]],yMin, yMax};
```

Which leads to an errors:

> ContourPlot::write: Tag Part in {x,y}[[1]] is Protected.  Show::gcomb:
>   "Could not combine the graphics objects in
>   Show[ContourPlot[fitFunc$2187,{{x,y}[[1]],xMin,xMax},{{x,y}[[2]],yMin,yMax}],"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The title of your post should be a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `ContourPlot` having attribute `HoldAll`, which prevents `Part` evaluating.

```
Attributes@ContourPlot
```

[image]

You can fix it like this.

```
data = {{6, 4, 7.92}, {6, 5, 9.31}, {6, 6, 9.74},
   {7, 4, 11.24}, {7, 5, 12.09}, {7, 6, 12.62},
   {8, 4, 14.31}, {8, 5, 14.58}, {8, 6, 16.16}};

fittingVarsList = {x, y};
{xMin, xMax} = Through[{Min, Max}@data[[All, 1]]];
{yMin, yMax} = Through[{Min, Max}@data[[All, 2]]];

fitFunc = Fit[data, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

This reproduces the problem :-

```
functionContourPlot = ContourPlot[fitFunc,
   {fittingVarsList[[1]], xMin, xMax},
   {fittingVarsList[[2]], yMin, yMax}];
```

[image]

The problem can be fixed by using `With` to create local variables :-

```
functionContourPlot = 
 With[{a = fittingVarsList[[1]], b = fittingVarsList[[2]]},
  ContourPlot[fitFunc, {a, xMin, xMax}, {b, yMin, yMax}]]
```

[image]

If you remove `HoldAll` from the attributes of `ContourPlot` the first version works ...

```
Unprotect@ContourPlot;
ClearAttributes[ContourPlot, HoldAll]
```

... but that would be reckless programming.